# Highlighting table row background in Android

Tags: java, android, highlight, android-tablelayout

I was having some problem when trying to highlight the background of specified row in table view, table view is a custom class for recycler view from another project.

I managed to set different image using canvas and bitmap but I not sure how to highlight the entire row, currently I am only able to highlight one cell only but not the entire row.

```
tableViewReminders.addCellRenderer(4, (canvas, selectedRow, parent) -> {
        Paint fillPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        List<List<String>> tableData = tableViewReminders.getRows();
        List<String> rowData = tableData.get(selectedRow);
        switch (rowData.get(4)) {
            default:
            case IS_SET:
                break;
            case IS_NOT_SET:
                break;
        }

        // getting the values of 2nd column of each row
        if(rowData.get(1).equals("Invalid")){
            // this part only managed to change the background color of 4th column but not the entire row 
            canvas.drawColor(Color.parseColor("#F3BF37"));
        }

        float left = canvas.getWidth() / 2.f - bitmap.getWidth() / 2.f;
        float top = canvas.getHeight() / 2.f - bitmap.getHeight() / 2.f;
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, left, top, fillPaint);
    });
```

The output for the code above:

[image]

Only the 4th column is highlighted but not the entire row. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
public void addCellRenderer(int col, ITableCellRenderer renderer) {
    rendererMap.put(col, renderer);
}

public interface ITableCellRenderer {
    public void onRender(Canvas canvas, int row, View parent);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

to highlight the complete row of a tablelayout use following code :

```
private OnClickListener tablerowOnClickListener = new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        //Highlight selected row
        //Highlight selected row
        for (int i = 1; i < tblItemDetail.getChildCount(); i++)
        {
            View row = tblItemDetail.getChildAt(i); 
            if (row == v)
            {
                row.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light));               
            }
            else
            {
                //Change this to your normal background color.
                row.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
            }
        }
        //...
    }
};
```

Comment: How can I adapt the solution to my problem? Because in my case, I need the if statement to check for which row to be highlighted first then proceed to set the background color.

Comment: Also I think I don't need a click listener as I just wanted to highlight the background of specific row. Do you have any ideas how to adapt the solution to my case?